# Pylint 2.14.0 outputs (bad-option-value) for no-self-use, no-space-check

Tags: pylint, pylintrc

I have updated pylint version
Now it is complaining for no-self-use  checker on .pylintrc file.

```
************* Module ../../.pylintrc
.pylintrc:1:0: E0015: Unrecognized option found: no-space-check (unrecognized-option)
.pylintrc:1:0: E0012: Bad option value for --disable. Don't recognize message no-self-use. (bad-option-value)
```

How can I fix it? disable comments does not work.
What should I change it for?

Answer (score 7):

From the [release note for 2.14](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/whatsnew/2/2.14/summary.html#removed-checkers):

> Moved no-self-use check to optional extension. You now need to explicitly enable this check using `load-plugins=pylint.extensions.no_self_use`.

For the unrecognized option you can remove it from the configuration it was used by a message related to formatting that was removed in pylint 2.6 and is now detected because 2.14 got better at parsing the conf and warn you.

Comment: what about `no-space-check`? do you know where it was moved to?

Comment: Yes ``The no-space-check option has been removed, it's no longer possible to consider empty line like a trailing-whitespace by using clever options.`` (https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/whatsnew/2/2.6/summary.html#summary-release-highlights)